# AWS EC2 Instance crashing nightly....only running Magento

Tags: php, linux, magento, amazon-web-services, magento2

I am running an AWS EC2 instance regular amazon linux flavor. It currently is running Magento 2, and only has 1gb ram as it is just a test server (free for a year!). It seems to be crashing every night, and I have to restart the instance to get SSH back up. checking var/log/messages shows the OOM killer is probably wiping out my ssh. For some reason, php and crond are showing up MANY MANY times. Can someone point me in the right debugging direction to narrow down where these PHP and Crond processes are coming from. Here is a snip from the messages log:

```
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55106.923629] Mem-Info:
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55106.924640] active_anon:115361 inactive_anon:115370 isolated_anon:0
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55106.924640]  active_file:708 inactive_file:495 isolated_file:0
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55106.924640]  unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55106.924640]  slab_reclaimable:2568 slab_unreclaimable:4748
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55106.924640]  mapped:879 shmem:1 pagetables:9876 bounce:0
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55106.924640]  free:1961 free_pcp:13 free_cma:0
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55106.938433] Node 0 DMA free:3972kB min:60kB low:72kB high:88kB active_anon:4832kB inactive_anon:4844kB active_file:96kB inactive_file:408kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15988kB managed:15904kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:28kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:244kB slab_unreclaimable:372kB kernel_stack:240kB pagetables:680kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:3212 all_unreclaimable? yes
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55106.957415] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 976 976 976
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55106.959655] Node 0 DMA32 free:3872kB min:3828kB low:4784kB high:5740kB active_anon:456612kB inactive_anon:456636kB active_file:2736kB inactive_file:1572kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:1032192kB managed:1003540kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:3488kB shmem:4kB slab_reclaimable:10028kB slab_unreclaimable:18620kB kernel_stack:3712kB pagetables:38824kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:52kB local_pcp:52kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:46664 all_unreclaimable? yes
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55106.988129] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55106.998441] Node 0 DMA: 43*4kB (E) 63*8kB (EM) 46*16kB (EM) 22*32kB (UEMR) 5*64kB (MR) 2*128kB (R) 3*256kB (R) 1*512kB (R) 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3972kB
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.008215] Node 0 DMA32: 274*4kB (UEMR) 19*8kB (R) 19*16kB (R) 13*32kB (R) 6*64kB (R) 2*128kB (R) 1*256kB (R) 2*512kB (R) 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3888kB
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.018312] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.023195] 1266 total pagecache pages
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.025399] 52 pages in swap cache
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.027423] Swap cache stats: add 710804, delete 710752, find 168673/295578
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.031609] Free swap  = 0kB
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.033507] Total swap = 1048572kB
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.035550] 262045 pages RAM
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.037322] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.039675] 7184 pages reserved
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.041568] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.046576] [ 1508]     0  1508     2866        1      11       3      238         -1000 udevd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.051456] [ 2026]     0  2026     2340       26      10       3       97             0 dhclient
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.056623] [ 2067]     0  2067    28018       24      26       3       86         -1000 auditd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.061685] [ 2085]     0  2085    61847       62      23       3      176             0 rsyslogd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.066646] [ 2101]     0  2101     1095        3       8       3       34             0 rngd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.071259] [ 2115]    32  2115     8823       13      21       3       84             0 rpcbind
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.079086] [ 2132]    29  2132     9965        1      24       3      198             0 rpc.statd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.084942] [ 2155]    81  2155     5448        1      15       3       76             0 dbus-daemon
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.079086] [ 2132]    29  2132     9965        1      24       3      198             0 rpc.statd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.084942] [ 2155]    81  2155     5448        1      15       3       76             0 dbus-daemon
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.090856] [ 2255]     0  2255    19454        0      41       3      212         -1000 sshd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.095863] [ 2280]    38  2280     7321       30      18       3      110             0 ntpd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.100734] [ 2290]     0  2290    12027        0      26       3      145             0 vsftpd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.105680] [ 2704]     0  2704    22241       43      45       3      420             0 sendmail
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.110775] [ 2712]    51  2712    20105        0      39       3      387             0 sendmail
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.116132] [ 2741]     0  2741   109631       11     198       4     1827             0 httpd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.121252] [ 2749]     0  2749    29880       26      15       3      119             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.126542] [ 2759]     0  2759     4267        0      13       3       45             0 atd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.131429] [ 2786]     0  2786     1078        1       8       3       23             0 mingetty
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.136825] [ 2788]     0  2788     1078        1       8       3       23             0 mingetty
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.142284] [ 2790]     0  2790     1078        1       8       3       23             0 mingetty
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.147440] [ 2792]     0  2792     1078        1       8       3       22             0 mingetty
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.152566] [ 2794]     0  2794     1078        1       8       3       23             0 mingetty
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.157974] [ 2796]     0  2796     1078        1       8       3       23             0 mingetty
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.163385] [ 2801]     0  2801     2719        1      10       3       93         -1000 udevd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.168763] [ 2802]     0  2802     2719        1      10       3       93         -1000 udevd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.173841] [ 2804]     0  2804     1615        1       9       3       31             0 agetty
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.178963] [ 2841]    48  2841   118657        4     215       4    11156             0 httpd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.184133] [ 2842]    48  2842   118657        4     215       4    11156             0 httpd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.189346] [ 2843]    48  2843   118657        4     215       4    11156             0 httpd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.194472] [ 2844]    48  2844   118657        4     215       4    11156             0 httpd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.199467] [ 2845]    48  2845   118657        4     215       4    11156             0 httpd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.204794] [ 2964]    48  2964   118657        4     215       4    11156             0 httpd
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.210517] [14102]   501 14102    59070    14152      70       3     1633             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.215530] [14111]   501 14111    36683        4      28       3      176             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.220551] [14120]   501 14120    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.225583] [14126]   501 14126   107278        0     149       3    17380             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.231030] [14131]   501 14131    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.236207] [14136]   501 14136   107021       17     149       4    17152             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.241384] [14141]   501 14141    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.246511] [14145]   501 14145   107278      928     150       3    16478             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.251493] [14171]   501 14171    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.257445] [14175]   501 14175   106680     4726     145       3    12126             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.262515] [14179]   501 14179   106394     5093     144       4    11479             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.267307] [14182]   501 14182    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.272187] [14187]   501 14187   106397     6416     146       3    10136             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.277067] [14191]   501 14191    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.282002] [14195]   501 14195   106218     4022     146       3    12348             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.287346] [14199]   501 14199   106072     6103     148       3    10142             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.292576] [14205]   501 14205    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.297652] [14208]   501 14208   105941     7965     146       3     8150             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.302522] [14213]   501 14213    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.307727] [14215]   501 14215    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.313074] [14218]   501 14218   106857    12307     146       3     4547             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.317977] [14221]   501 14221   105659     9303     143       4     6486             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.322666] [14224]   501 14224   105136    10941     146       3     4292             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.327764] [14225]   501 14225    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.333212] [14226]   501 14226    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.338541] [14227]   501 14227    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.343450] [14230]   501 14230   104049     9848     139       3     4315             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.348530] [14231]   501 14231    91525      259     117       3     1141             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.353693] [14233]   501 14233   104752    10345     142       4     4562             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.358841] [14234]   501 14234    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.364203] [14235]   501 14235    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.369257] [14236]   501 14236    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.374474] [14240]   501 14240   103856     9789     140       3     4155             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.379243] [14241]   501 14241    91525      607     120       4      727             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.384435] [14242]   501 14242   104753    10925     141       4     3897             0 php
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.389379] [14272]   501 14272    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
Mar  3 12:40:14 ip-172-31-31-176 kernel: [55107.394313] [14273]   501 14273    36683        3      28       3      177             0 crond
```

Comment: do you have a crontab in place that runs a PHP script?

Comment: Yes there are 3 scripts that run every minute as required by magento2.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that a t2.micro does not have the necessary computing power to use with Magento. It looks like your cron scripts are taking too long and cron ends up starting more of them until oom-killer has to kick in.

I would first check the CPU credits in the EC2 monitoring to see if you haven't depleted them. If you have, you will probably want to switch to t2.small or bigger (which is not free).

Comment: I copied the link to the monitoring graph below. It shows my credits go as high as 1.44 then drop off, because I think the OOM kicks in.
[EC2 Monitoring Graph](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-west-2#metrics:graph=~(metrics~(~(~'AWS*2fEC2~'CPUCreditUsage~'InstanceId~'i-79c04dbe))~period~3600~stat~'Maximum~start~'-P1D~end~'P0D~yAxis~(left~null~right~null)~region~'us-west-2))

Comment: can you post a screenshot instead? This link seems to be to your own AWS console. 

But if your CPU credits are around zero, it pretty much means that you need more CPU than what you currently have. T2 class instances do not have 100% of CPU available all the time, only when you have credits. You can read more about it here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html

Answer (score -2):

You can try to add multiple instances and try with Load Balancing.

Comment: If it is the hardware that is incapable, I would rather just upgrade to a larger VPS.